# Setting Usercontrol's custom dependency proeprty by xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

Here is my user control(MonthCal)'s code behind.

```
public partial class MonthCal : UserControl
{
    public DayOfWeek StartDayOfWeek { get { return (DayOfWeek)GetValue(StartDayOfWeekProperty); } set { SetValue(StartDayOfWeekProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDayOfWeekProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StartDayOfWeek", typeof(DayOfWeek), typeof(MonthCellHeader), new UIPropertyMetadata(DayOfWeek.Sunday, StartDayOfWeek_PropertyChanged));
    //...
}
```

and also, here is a xaml of the MonthCal.

```
<UserControl x:Class="GCDR.MonthCal"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

And so, How can I set the 'StartDayOfWeek' dependency property in xaml? as you guys know, the following code is impossible:

```
<UserControl ...
             StartDayOfWeek="Sunday">
</UserControl>
```

Please give me a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the dependency property in markup of the UserControl but you can use it when you place instance of the user control somewhere like so:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 local:StartDayOfWeek="Friday" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With in your user control you can bind some other property to your dependency property like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl1},Path=StartDayOfWeek}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot set StartDayOfWeek is that UserControl in XAML does not have StartDayOfWeek dependency property, in other word UserControl type is not MonthCal type.

As, in XAML, UserControl is base class of UserControl1, you can define MonthCal inherited UserControl and then declare MonthCal in XAML.

XAML

```
<local:MonthCal x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow"
                Height="350" Width="525"
                StartDayOfWeek="Monday">
    <Grid></Grid>
</local:MonthCal>
```

Codebehinde

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MonthCal : Window
    {
        public DayOfWeek StartDayOfWeek { get { return (DayOfWeek)GetValue(StartDayOfWeekProperty); } set { SetValue(StartDayOfWeekProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDayOfWeekProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("StartDayOfWeek", typeof(DayOfWeek), typeof(MonthCal), new UIPropertyMetadata(DayOfWeek.Sunday, StartDayOfWeek_PropertyChanged));

        private static void StartDayOfWeek_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : MonthCal
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```